# How to calculate current index position in a query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-custom-search

[Google custom search api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list) says to use the parameter `num` to specify the number of image results, this goes from 1 to 10 only. I have been looking around how to sort of repeat the search to get more than 10 images and [I found this article](http://thejavatar.com/retrieve-pictures-from-google-search-engine-using-jquery/). He says:

> Even though there is a limit of 8 pictures we can get from the server
>   in a single query, if we modify the `start parameter` we can ultimately
>   retrieve more than 8 results.

From the docs linked above the `start` means ***The index of the first result to return.***

Therefore I have applied what he used to run a query and I have applied it to my own code but I get now 0 images.

```
var myCx = "MY_CX";
var myKey = "MY_KEY";
var lastQueriedName;
var termS = "hello";

// This bit is from the link which runs against the currentSTARTposition

var currentSearchPosition = 0;
function calculateStartPosition(termS, shift) {
if (lastQueriedName === termS) {
    currentSearchPosition += shift;
    if (currentSearchPosition < 0) {
        currentSearchPosition = 0;
    }
    if (currentSearchPosition >= 100) {
        currentSearchPosition = 92;
    }
} else {
    lastQueriedName = termS;
    currentSearchPosition = 0;
}
   return currentSearchPosition;
}

// This is my own code which works only if 
// I don't insert the above function and I remove start: position

$.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1", {
        q: termS,
        alt: "json",
        searchType: "image",
        cx: myCx,
        start: currentSearchPosition,
        num: 10,
        key: myKey,
        rights: "cc_publicdomain",
        filter: "1",
        imgType: "photo",
        fileType: "jpg"
    },
    function (data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i,item){    
            $(".my_images .row").append('<div class="col-sm-4"><div class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="' + item.link + '"></div></div>');
        });
    });
};
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually this is how I am grabbing more than 10 images, i repeat the query and use the start parameter: I save the start value between calls

```
function createGoogleImagesLoader(initialValue) {
       var _start = initialValue || 1;
       var imagesCount = 10;

       return function() {
            $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1", {
                ...
                num: imagesCount,
                start: _start
             },..);
            _start += imagesCount;

       }
    }

var googleImages = createGoogleImagesLoader();
googleImages() // load from 0 to 10
googleImages() // load from 10 to 20 etc.
```